# I want to stop the main activity through notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an android application which will play online radio , even the user minimize the app. what i want to do is , when ever the user press the notification, it should stop or destroy  my main activity, i have the code to open the main activity through notification , and it works fine, i want to change the code as per mu concern , all i need is some help...

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic);
  builder.setContentTitle("RadioPlanet");
    builder.setContentText("Touch here to Open");int mll=001;
   PendingIntent contentIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  NotificationManager mNotification=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNotification.notify(mll,builder.build());
```

after adding the answer in oncreate

```
 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }

    };


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);






  NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic);
  builder.setContentTitle("RadioPlanet");
    builder.setContentText("Touch here to Open");int mll=001;
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");


    Context context=getApplicationContext();

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , intent, 0);


    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);


  NotificationManager mNotification=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNotification.notify(mll,builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using broadcast receiver for this purpose.

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    finish();
}

};
```

Then in onCreate() of activity

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And then your PendingIntent in your notification should have action of "android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY" and for safety a package of your activity's package

As

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , intent, 0);
```

Then add it to your notification by using the setContentIntent(pIntent) when building the notification with the Notification.Builder.

Comment: how to call the receiver , through notification

Comment: it worked? dont forget to accept the answer if it worked

Comment: use this instead of context.

Comment: change context to , MainActivity.this , and add code of BroadcastReceive out side onCreate method.

Comment: its closing but its looks like minimizing , coz my online radio from webview is not stopping

Comment: Use System.exit(0); instead of finish

Comment: it workd , but after exiting , notification is still there, i want to clear the notification too

Comment: Use NotificationManager.cancelAll(); to clear all notifications or NotificationManager.cancel(notificationId); for particular notification

Comment: Yes, First make NotificationManager in class , and then use that object to destroy in onRecieve